Angular routing broken on deployment
I just deployed my production Angular 17 app to a server. The process of ng build and simply copying the files over to the server went fine. But, when I click any of the nav links, I get this error in the browser:
404 Not Found
nginx/1.24.0 (Ubuntu)

Compared to past builds and deployments, I do notice there are less files and some differences with the angular.json file. Any tips? Thanks in advance!
Fairly simple Angular 17 app with 4 nav links. Works fine in ng serve locally. Uses a simple dotnet API for backend. Landing page works fine. Google searching did not find much. Angular 17 seems to be pretty new.

are you using <a href=... instead of <a [routerLink]=...?

that is not everything. you should setup handling for other routes in your nginx. otherwise refreshing the page on all routes except / would result in 404. usually it looks like this location / {     root /data/www;     try_files $uri /index.html 404;     }
